# Yii is handling $_GET for clean url only

Tags: yii, get, yii-url-manager

i am trying to allow accessing the $_GET for both clean url and normal get request in YII (Yii 1.1.14), so for example if i have a controller Cities and action getCities that var_dump($_GET) only

```
1- http://example.com/cities/getCities/country_id/100
==> the output is array(1) { ["country_id"]=> string(3) "100" }
2- http://example.com/cities/getCities?country_id=100
==> the output is array(0) { }
```

my urlManager is

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'class'     => 'ext.localeurls.LocaleUrlManager',
    'languageParam'    => 'lang', //  Name of the parameter that contains the desired language when constructing a URL
    'urlFormat'       => 'path',
    'showScriptName'  => false,
    'caseSensitive'   => false,
    'rules'=>array(
        'login'=>'/home/login'
    )
),
```

how could i allow Yii to recognize $_GET in both cases above?

**EDIT**
i am using nginx 1.6. GET params (?x=y) is working fine on other Yii projects, only this project doesn't. I changed the web-server to apache, and i got it working on this project!!! although this project has the same nginx configurations like others!!

Comment: I suspect the query string isn't being pushed to the `index.php` file of your project. Check your url-rewrite rules

Comment: Do you mean in nginx? if so, i tried to create a test file (test.php) on the root, and i passed it some params /test.php?x=value ... in var_dump($_GET), it shows all values that i passed in the link. this means that the problem is at YII side (not nginx)